# Parsing lines containing "\n" in with Apache Beam's `ReadFromText`

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have a `.csv` file that I am trying to read using `apache_beam.io.ReadFromText()` within a pipeline (`beam` is an alias for `apache_beam`):

```py
reader = beam.io.ReadFromText(csv_path, skip_header_lines=1)
```

I have a row reader class like the following:

```py
class RowReader(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, row):
        row_delimited = row.split(",")
        text_1 = str(row_delimited[1]).encode()
        text_2 = str(row_delimited[4]).encode()
        image_1 = tf.io.read_file(row_delimited[-3]).numpy()
        image_2 = tf.io.read_file(row_delimited[-2]).numpy()
        label = row_delimited[-1]
        
        yield {"text_1": text_1, "image_1": image_1,
                "text_2": text_2, "image_2": image_2,
                "label": label}
```

One of the rows in the csv file has an entry like the following:

[image]

But `beam.io.ReadFromText()` is splitting on the basis of `\n`s. But the problem with this is that the row is just this:

```sh
1357240852939218946,"#IndiaFightsCorona:
```

Whereas the actual first element after the `,` is:

```sh
#IndiaFightsCorona:\n\nNearly 4.5 million beneficiaries vaccinated against #COVID19 in 19 days.\n\nIndia is the fastest country to cross landmark of vaccinating 4 million beneficiaries in merely 18 days.\n\n#StaySafe #IndiaWillWin #Unite2FightCorona
```

I have tried passing `strip_trailing_newlines=False` to `ReadFromText()` but it did not help. How can make `beam` ignore the `\n` splitting?

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did. Defined the `RowReader` as the following:

```py
class RowReader(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, row):
        text_1 = str(row[1]).encode()
        text_2 = str(row[4]).encode()
        image_1 = tf.io.read_file(row[7]).numpy()
        image_2 = tf.io.read_file(row[8]).numpy()
        label = int(row[9])

        yield {"text_1": text_1, "image_1": image_1,
                "text_2": text_2, "image_2": image_2,
                "label": label}
```

Then defined the pipeline as follows:

```py
with beam.Pipeline(args.runner, options=options) as pipe:
  df = (
        pipe 
        | read_csv(csv_path)
      )
  pc = to_pcollection(df)
  _ = (
        pc
        | 'Decode from CSV' >> beam.ParDo(RowReader())
        ...
      )
```

`read_csv` is imported as `from apache_beam.dataframe.io import read_csv` and `to_pcollection` is imported as `from apache_beam.dataframe.convert import to_pcollection`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use the `skip_trailing_newlines` flag [according to the docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.6.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.ReadFromText):

```py
reader = beam.io.ReadFromText(csv_path, skip_header_lines=1, skip_trailing_newlines=False)
```

Does that work now?

Comment: Actually not. I probably misunderstood that argument. It's likely having no effect.

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking. Can you print out as a code block the actual line you're trying to parse rather than showing it as a screenshot? I think it'd be easier to help that way

Comment: Added. See if it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

`apache_beam.io.ReadFromText` assumes all newlines delineate records. If your csv file has records spanning lines there are a couple of options.

(1) Create a PCollection of file names (e.g. using [MatchFiles](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.31.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html#apache_beam.io.fileio.MatchFiles) or just globbling and using `beam.Create`) followed by a `DoFn` that opens the file (possibly using the calls from [filesystems](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.31.0/apache_beam.io.filesystems.html) to support GCS, HDFS, etc.) and yields the rows using Python's CSV reader. (The downside over ReadFromText is that this forces the entire file to be read in a single worker.)

or (2) Use `apache_beam.dataframe.io.read_csv` from Beam's [Dataframe APIs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/). This will give a deferred dataframe, which you can use as if it were a Pandas Dataframe, or convert into a PCollection with `apache_beam.dataframe.convert.to_pcollection`.

Comment: So, do you mean something like I first read the CSV with `apache_beam.dataframe.io.read_csv` and then make it a PCollection object. Then I pass it as a pipeline component while building my pipeline?

Comment: For the first option, I did something like: `gcs_file = beam.io.filesystems.FileSystems.open(csv_path)` and then `csv_reader = csv.reader(io.TextIOWrapper(gcs_file))`. In this case we have a problem with the header.